# Duplicate config files with .dpkg-dist extension

Tags: linux, debian, debian-squeeze

I have noticed a number of duplicate files such as the default Apache vHost, I have both:
 - default
 - default.dpkg-dist

Will Apache still read the .dpkg-dist file extension?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, no installed package should need files with the `*.dpkg*` extensions.  These files show up when you are upgrading a package.  If you you choose to keep your existing package the configuration that came with the upgraded package is saved as `.dpkg-dist`.  If you choose to use the new configuration then your old file will be saved as `.dpkg-old`.

Comment: Is there perhaps some documentation on this that you could link to?

Comment: @SamB, This kind of mentions it. http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-pkg-conffiles.html  I am not sure where the official doc is anymore.